# Glide custom URI scheme

Tags: android, android-glide

I need to load images from my database, I store them in blobs just like android. Each image is represented by my costume URI. How can I work it out with [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)?

I want to benefit from Glide cache and fast loading.

Is there a proper way of doing this?

Comment: Instead of storing images in blob to database why don't you store it on internal/external store of device and store path of those images to database and then you can simply retrieve those image with using path and load with glide.

Comment: @RajeshPanchal I don't want to change they way images are stored, just integrate with Glide.

Answer (score 1):

you can register **customize ModelLoader class** to Glide by calling Glide.get(context).register() method. and in your ModelLoader, you can tell Glide how to load image resources from your database by implement **getResourceFetcher** method and return a customize DataFetcher instance.

here's a example:

DBImageUri class:

```
public class DBImageUri {

private String uriString;

public DBImageUri(String uriString){
    this.uriString = uriString;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return uriString;
}
}
```

DBDataFetcher class:

```
public class DBDataFetcher implements DataFetcher<InputStream> {

private DBImageUri uri;
private int width;
private int height;

private InputStream stream;

public DBDataFetcher(DBImageUri uri, int width, int height){
    this.uri = uri;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

@Override
public InputStream loadData(Priority priority){
    String uriString = this.uri.toString();

    stream = //**load image based on uri, and return InputStream for this image. this is where you do the actual image from database loading process**;

    return stream;
}

@Override
public String getId(){
    //width & height should be ignored if you return same image resources for any resolution (return uri.toString();)
    return uri.toString() + "_" + width + "_" + height;
}

@Override
public void cleanup(){
    if (stream != null) {
        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Ignore
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void cancel(){

}
}
```

DBModelLoader class:

```
public class DBModelLoader implements ModelLoader<DBImageUri, InputStream> {

@Override
public DataFetcher<InputStream> getResourceFetcher(DBImageUri model, int width, int height){

    return new DBDataFetcher(model, width, height);
}

public static class Factory implements ModelLoaderFactory<DBImageUri, InputStream>{

    @Override
    public ModelLoader<DBImageUri, InputStream> build(Context context, GenericLoaderFactory factories){
        return new DBModelLoader();
    }

    @Override
    public void teardown(){

    }

}
}
```

and then you add ModelLoader to Glide registry by calling:

```
Glide.get(context).register(DBImageUri.class, InputStream.class, new DBModelLoader.Factory());
```

now you can load you database images:

```
Glide.with(context).load(new DBImageUri(/*your unique id string for database image*/)).into(imageview);
```

Comment: sorry I didn't notice that new Registry class was not included in v3.7.0 which is the latest release version, I edited my answer with example